# Oracle DDL execution with immediate mode and errors

Tags: sql, oracle, show, mode

After doing about two hours' worth of research on various issues with execute immediate and error handling, I don't think I've encountered exactly the problem I am about to present. I have reduced my issue to the sample below. The issue is:

When I execute a procedure create in immediate mode with the create text in a variable and a syntax error in the create text, the execute immediate call throws an error indicating that it failed. But I can't get at the underlying error or its text.

However, when I create the same proc directly in sqlplus (w/o intermediate mode), getting the error works perfectly.

So, how does one get at the error that causes immediate mode to fail?

I have interspersed the output with my comments (MOP) and reduced the number of blank lines:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Mar 25 15:57:06 2013
Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> set serveroutput on

SQL> declare
  2    eSQL varchar(568);
  3  begin
  4        eSQL := 'create or replace procedure MOPMOP
  5  as
  6  begin
  7      select 1 from dual;
  8  end;
  9  ';
 10        execute immediate eSQL;
 11  end;
 12  /
ERROR:
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at line 10
Warning: PL/SQL compilation errors.
```

This is good. There's a compilation error. So, now let me ask what that compilation error is:

```
SQL> show errors;
No errors.
```

This is no good. There's a compilation error. What was it!?!?!? Contrast that with:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure MOPMOP
  2  as
  3  begin
  4      select 1 from dual;
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

This is good. There's a compilation error. So, now let me ask what that compilation error is:

```
SQL> show errors;
Errors for PROCEDURE MOPMOP:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/5  PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
SQL>
```

And this is good. There's a compilation error. And now I know what is is.

So, how do I get intermediate mode to spit out the underlying (00428) error?

Answer (score 2):

when you run `show errors` on its own it will show the errors for any prior "create" / "alter" that sqlplus itself did, which is this case is nothing (as it was hidden from sqlplus because of the dynamic SQL)

you have to expcitly say you want to see the errors of the procedure for this case:

```
SQL> declare
  2    eSQL varchar(568);
  3  begin
  4        eSQL := 'create or replace procedure MOPMOP
  5  as
  6  begin
  7      select 1 from dual;
  8  end;
  9  ';
 10        execute immediate eSQL;
 11  end;
 12  /
ERROR:
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at line 10



Warning: PL/SQL compilation errors.

SQL> show errors procedure mopmop
Errors for PROCEDURE MOPMOP:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/5      PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
SQL>
```

as the create ran server side and not through sqlplus, sqlplus didn't know about the failure, so couldnt fetch the errors correctly.

also if you had a prior failure, it would retain that:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure MOPMOP2
  2  as
  3  begin
  4      select 1 from dual;
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> declare
  2    eSQL varchar(568);
  3  begin
  4        eSQL := 'create or replace procedure MOPMOP
  5  as
  6  begin
  7      select 1 from dual;
  8  end;
  9  ';
 10        execute immediate eSQL;
 11  end;
 12  /
ERROR:
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at line 10



Warning: PL/SQL compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE MOPMOP2:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/5      PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use select 1 from dual... in PL/SQL. Must use select into. In both cases you are creating PL/SQL procedures not some SQL script.

```
declare
   x number;
begin 
  select 1 into x from dual;
end;
/

declare
  procedure MOPMOP
  as
    x number;
 begin
   select 1 into x from dual;
   dbms_output.put_line(x);
 end MOPMOP;
begin
 MOPMOP;
end;
/
```

Avoid ORA-24344 - although I probably would never use dynamic sql for this:

```
declare
  eSQL varchar(568);
  x number;
begin  
  eSQL := 'create or replace procedure MOPMOP as 
           begin 
             select 1 into x from dual; 
           end;';            
  execute immediate eSQL;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
end;
/
```

Comment: I think his code is just illustrating the need and allows us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, this was just a repro.

Comment: @mpersico-just FYI: you will see the same error message even if you use correct syntax as in my examples. Comment the exception part in my code and you will see the same error message. In my code I shown you how to fix the code and how to get rid of the message. Just trying to help and not caring for scores...